# Floating point comparison program

Tags: c++, floating-point

I made a small program to compare floating-point values by running multiple tests to a single pair of floats. I have added extra checks for under/overflow and allowing tolerance.

How can I improve it further?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cctype>
#include <cfloat>
#include <limits>
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>

template <size_t size>
struct Types {
    typedef void int_type;
};

template <>
struct Types<4> {
    typedef int int_type;
    typedef unsigned int uint_type;
};

template <>
struct Types<8> {
    typedef __int64 int_type;
    typedef unsigned __int64 uint_type;
};

template <typename T>
class Float
{
public:
    typedef typename Types<sizeof(T)>::uint_type bit_type;
    typedef typename T value_type;

    static const bit_type bit_count = 8 * sizeof(value_type);
    static const bit_type fraction_count = std::numeric_limits<value_type>::digits - 1;
    static const bit_type exponent_count = bit_count - 1 - fraction_count;

    static const bit_type sign_mask = static_cast<bit_type>(1) << (bit_count - 1);
    static const bit_type fraction_mask = ~static_cast<bit_type>(0) >> (exponent_count + 1);
    static const bit_type exponent_mask = ~(sign_mask | fraction_mask);
    static const bit_type max_ulps = static_cast<bit_type>(4);

    explicit Float(const T& x) { value = x; }

    const value_type &data_float() const { return value; }
    const bit_type &data_bits() const { return bit; }

    bit_type exponent_bits() const { return (exponent_mask & bit); }
    bit_type sign_bits() const { return sign; }
    bit_type fraction_bits() const { return fraction; }

    bool is_infinity()
    {
        return ((bit & ~sign_mask) == exponent_mask);
    }

    bool is_nan() const {
        bool nan = true;
        nan &= (exponent_mask & bit) == exponent_mask;
        nan &= (fraction_mask & bit) != static_cast<bit_type>(0);
        return nan;
    }

    static bit_type to_biased(bit_type bits) {
        return (sign_mask & bits) ? (~bits + 1) : (sign_mask | bits);
    }

    static bit_type distance(bit_type bits1, bit_type bits2) {
        const bit_type biased1 = to_biased(bits1);
        const bit_type biased2 = to_biased(bits2);
        return (biased1 >= biased2) ? (biased1 - biased2) : (biased2 - biased1);
    }

private:
    union
    {
        value_type value;
        bit_type bit;

        struct {
            bit_type fraction : fraction_count;
            bit_type exponent : exponent_count;
            bit_type sign : 1;
        };
    };
};

#define PRINT_DEBUG_INFO 1

template <typename T> static inline
std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, bool>
almost_equals(const T& lhs, const T& rhs)
{
    Float<T> f1(lhs), f2(rhs);

#if PRINT_DEBUG_INFO
    std::cout << std::setfill(' ') << f1 << '\n' << f2;
    std::cout << std::setfill('-') << std::setw(71) << ' ' << std::setfill(' ') << std::endl;
#endif

    const Float<T>::bit_type distance = Float<T>::distance(f1.data_bits(), f2.data_bits());
    const T abs_f1 = std::abs(f1.data_float());
    const T abs_f2 = std::abs(f2.data_float());
    const T diff = std::max(std::abs(abs_f1 - abs_f2), std::numeric_limits<T>::min());
    const T sum = std::min(std::abs(abs_f1 + abs_f2), std::numeric_limits<T>::max());

    const T tolerance = static_cast<T>(0.000001);

    bool under_flow = diff < std::numeric_limits<T>::min() || abs_f1 < std::numeric_limits<T>::min() || abs_f2 < std::numeric_limits<T>::min();
    bool over_flow = diff > std::numeric_limits<T>::max() || abs_f1 > std::numeric_limits<T>::max() || abs_f2 > std::numeric_limits<T>::max();

    bool sign = (f1.sign_bits() ^ f2.sign_bits()) == 1 && !(under_flow ^ over_flow);

    bool inff = (f1.is_infinity() ^ f2.is_infinity()) == 1;
    bool nan = (f1.is_nan() ^ f2.is_nan()) == 1;

    bool assign = f1.data_float() == f2.data_float();
    bool ulp = Float<T>::distance(f1.data_bits(), f2.data_bits()) < Float<T>::max_ulps;
    bool fixed_epsilon = diff < tolerance;
    bool relative_epsilon = diff < std::numeric_limits<T>::epsilon() * sum;

#if PRINT_DEBUG_INFO
    std::cout << "\n"
        << "distance         = " << distance << '\n'
        << "diff             = " << diff << '\n'
        << "sum              = " << sum << '\n'
        << "min              = " << std::numeric_limits<T>::min() << '\n'
        << "max              = " << std::numeric_limits<T>::max() << '\n'
        << "---------------- \n"
        << std::boolalpha
        << std::setw(15) << "under_flow       = " << std::setw(7) << under_flow << '\n'
        << std::setw(15) << "over_flow        = " << std::setw(7) << over_flow << '\n'
        << std::setw(15) << "diff sign        = " << std::setw(7) << sign << '\n'
        << std::setw(15) << "inf              = " << std::setw(7) << inff << '\n'
        << std::setw(15) << "nan              = " << std::setw(7) << nan << '\n'
        << "---------------- \n"
        << std::setw(15) << "assign           = " << std::setw(7) << assign << '\n'
        << std::setw(15) << "ulp              = " << std::setw(7) << ulp << '\n'
        << std::setw(15) << "fixed_epsilon    = " << std::setw(7) << fixed_epsilon << '\n'
        << std::setw(15) << "relative_epsilon = " << std::setw(7) << relative_epsilon << "\n\n";
    std::cout << std::setfill('-') << std::setw(71) << ' ' << std::setfill(' ') << "\n\n";
#endif

    if (sign || nan || inff) return false;

    return assign || ulp || fixed_epsilon || relative_epsilon;
}

// -- debug prints --
template <typename T> static inline std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Float<T>& f)
{
    os << std::fixed << std::setprecision(25) << std::left;

    os << "float    = " << std::setw(10) << std::dec << f.data_float() << "\n";

    os << "bits     = " << std::setw(10) << std::dec << f.data_bits() << " : 0x"
        << std::setw(10) << std::hex << f.data_bits() << " : "
        << std::setw(32) << std::bitset<32>(f.data_bits()) << "\n";

    os << "sign     = " << std::setw(10) << std::dec << f.sign_bits() << " : 0x"
        << std::setw(10) << std::hex << f.sign_bits() << " : "
        << std::setw(32) << std::bitset<32>(f.sign_bits()) << "\n";

    os << "exponent = " << std::setw(10) << std::dec << f.exponent_bits() << " : 0x"
        << std::setw(10) << std::hex << f.exponent_bits() << " : "
        << std::setw(32) << std::bitset<32>(f.exponent_bits()) << "\n";

    os << "fraction = " << std::setw(10) << std::dec << f.fraction_bits() << " : 0x"
        << std::setw(10) << std::hex << f.fraction_bits() << " : "
        << std::setw(32) << std::bitset<32>(f.fraction_bits()) << "\n\n";

    os << std::resetiosflags(std::ios_base::fixed | std::ios_base::floatfield) << std::dec;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    float a = 1.0f;
    float b = 3.0f;
    bool result = almost_equals(a, b);
    std::cout << "a == b : " << std::boolalpha << result << "!\n\n";

    float c = a / b;
    float d = b / a;
    result = almost_equals(c,1/d);
    std::cout << "a/b == a/b : " << std::boolalpha << result << "!\n\n";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good effort with lots of useful debug to see the inner working of the task.

---

Biggest design concern: lack of control on how "almost" `almost_equals()` operates.  I'd expect a 3rd, perhaps optional, parameter to gauge "closeness".

From a design stand-point, code is mixing absolute and relative in determining the the return of `almost_equals()` and is incapable of returning a sensible result based on just one of those.  Perhaps 2 functions:

```
almost_equals_rel(value_type a, value_type b, uint_type ulp_abs_difference);
almost_equals_abs(value_type a, value_type b, value_type max_abs_difference);
```

---

This and that:

1. Code uses a fixed `tolerance`, yet uses templated code.   A value of `0.000001` is quite arbitrary *and not justified* in code.  Might make sense for `float`, yet not `double`.  IMO, the `tolerance` assessment detracts from this code.

   ```
   // Why the magic number 0.000001?
   const T tolerance = static_cast<T>(0.000001);
   ```
2. `-0.0` has the same value of `0.0`, yet incorrectly fails `almost_equals()` due to differ signs.
3. Values of 7, 10 and 15 throughout code should 1) be driven by a common named constants and 2) not a magic number.  IMO, for typical `float` and `double` I would expect 9 and 17 significant digits printed to allow round-tripping the text back to the FP variable.  (Of course this is mostly debug code.)
4. `bool nan = (f1.is_nan() ^ f2.is_nan()) == 1;` goes against the spirit of IEEE math.  Even if both `f1,f2` are both NaNs with the same bit pattern, they are not equal.
5. Unsigned fixed width types makes sense for `double`.  I'd use `int64_t int_type` rather than `__int64 int_type`  Potable code should use fixed width for `struct Types<4>`

   ```
   struct Types<4> {
     //typedef int int_type;
     //typedef unsigned int uint_type;
     typedef int32_t int_type;
     typedef uint32_t uint_type;
   };
   ```
6. For code to function correctly, it assumes the endian of integers and FP is the same.  Certainly common, but not specified and exceptions exists.

   ```
   union {
     value_type value;
     bit_type bit;
   ```
7. Further, code assumes the bit packing/bit fields are in the desired order.

   ```
   struct {
       bit_type fraction : fraction_count;
       bit_type exponent : exponent_count;
       bit_type sign : 1;
   };
   // or should it be  
   struct {
       bit_type sign : 1;
       bit_type exponent : exponent_count;
       bit_type fraction : fraction_count;
   };
   ```
8. A comment that applies to C, unsure about C++: bit fields are well defined for integer types `unsigned`, `signed int` and maybe `bool`.  So a bit field of type `__int64` may lack portability.  Higher portable code would use shifts and masks rather than bit fields to control endian, range and padding issues.
9. `int main()` only exercises `float`.  Recommend adding a `double` example.  Also compare values `a,b` that are both about `1e30` or `1e-30`.  The test set is much to small.